# Best way to blur all inputs on page?

Tags: javascript, blur

I am trying to blur all the inputs on the page, to show error styling.
I am trying to follow this [blur documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/blur).

My attempt is to grab all the inputs and then apply blur...

```
document.querySelectorAll('input').blur();
```

But I simply get the error, blur is not a function.
What is the correct approach?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, there is no point un bluring more than one input element : only one can have focus at a time, so only one can "blur" at a time.

But for the sake of the example, here is how it could be achieved:

`document.querySelectorAll('input')` returns an array-like object, so:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input')).forEach(el => el.blur())
```

Comment: The point for me was to trigger a code that was adding visual cues what fields are invalid, without me knowing where that code is or how it works. This answer was correct +1